# Getting error when attempting to create Company using google example

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am trying to create a company with Google Talent Solution on v3 and I am getting the error.  (Note if I rollback to v2 I am successful, however v2 appears to be deprecated)

```
Error: Unable to load endpoint jobs("v3"): ctr is not a constructor
    at Object.getAPI (/Users/me/Sites/match/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/shared/src/apiIndex.js:37:15)
    at GoogleApis.jobs (/Users/me/Sites/match/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/jobs/index.js:22:18)
    at google.auth.getApplicationDefault (/Users/me/Sites/match/utils/company.js:21:35)
    at /Users/me/Sites/match/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:179:45
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

This appears to be that apiIndex.js does not have v3 as a supported version. I am using the latest version of googleapis 32.0.0 from npm.

Here is the URL where I am trying the example:

https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin

```
// Imports the Google APIs client library
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const projectId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT;

// Acquires credentials
google.auth.getApplicationDefault((err, authClient) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Failed to acquire credentials');
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
    authClient = authClient.createScoped([
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/jobs'
    ]);
  }

  // Instantiates an authorized client
  const jobService = google.jobs({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: authClient
  });

  const request = {
    parent: `projects/${projectId}`,
  };

  // Lists companies
  jobService.projects.companies.list(request, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to retrieve companies! ' + err);
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Request ID: ${result.data.metadata.requestId}`);

    const companies = result.data.companies || [];

    if (companies.length) {
      console.log('Companies:');
      companies.forEach((company) => console.log(company.name));
    } else {
      console.log(`No companies found.`);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you get any solution?

Comment: @Miteshjadav see my answer below for a code example on how I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved after contacting the maintainers of the node module.

Here is a sample of my request should anyone else find this and need help.

```
   const { google } = require('googleapis');

module.exports = () => {
  /**
  * createServiceConnection() Create a service connection to google for future queries
  * @return {object} service connection object
  */
  async function createServiceConnection() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      google.auth.getApplicationDefault((err, authClient) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to acquire credentials', err); // eslint-disable-line no-console
          return reject({ code: 500, message: 'Failed to acquire credentials' });
        }

        if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
          authClient = authClient.createScoped([
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/jobs'
          ]);
        }

        // Instantiates an authorized client
        const jobService = google.jobs({
          version: 'v3',
          auth: authClient
        });

        return resolve(jobService);
      });
    });
  }


  return {
    createServiceConnection
  };
};
```

Called with this

```
  app.service = await googleUtil.createServiceConnection();
```

And then elsewhere I use it like

```
const data = {
  parent: `projects/${process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}`,
  requestBody: {
    company: _data
  }
};

result = await app.service.projects.companies.create(data);
```